# How to access object struct fields of subclasses from a Python C extension?

Tags: python-3.x, python-c-api

I'm writing a Python C extension that wraps an external C library. In the original library there are structs (of type `T` for the sake of the discussion), so my extension class looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
  PyObject_HEAD
  T *cdata;
} TWrapperBase;
```

I also need to look up pointers in Python from time to time, so I exposed a read-only field `_cdata` that is a `cdata` pointer as `unsigned long long` (yes, I know it's not very portable, but it's out of scope now).

Then, I want to be able to add some more methods in Python, but I can't just append them to a class declared in C, so I subclass it and add my new methods:

```
class TWrapper(TWrapperBase):
    ...
```

Now, in my C extension code I need a way of accesing `cdata` field, so I can pass it to library functions. I know that `self` won't be an instance of `TWrapperBase`, but rather `TWrapper` (this Python version). **What is the proper way to do this?**

```
static PyObject * doStuff(PyObject *self)
{
  T *cdata_ptr;
  // How to get a pointer to cdata?
  //
  // This looks very unsafe to me, do I have any guarantee of
  // the subclass memory layout?
  // 1. cdata_ptr = ((TWrapperBase*)self)->cdata
  //
  // This is probably safe, but it seems to be a bit of a hassle
  // to query it with a string key
  // 2. cdata_ptr = PyLong_AsVoidPtr(PyObject_GetAttrString(self, "_cdata"))
  do_important_library_stuff(cdata_ptr);
  Py_INCREF(self);
  return self;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing `Py_INCREF(self);` *after* you do the library stuff?

Comment: Is that why option 1. looks unsafe to you?

Comment: I'm `INCREF`ing it only because it's a return type and returned objects are stolen references.

Comment: You may want to `INCREF` before you do anything with the object, such as accessing `cdata`. As you say, it is a stolen reference and the destructor may invalidate `self->cdata`.

Comment: You're right, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  // This looks very unsafe to me, do I have any guarantee of
  // the subclass memory layout?
  // 1. cdata_ptr = ((TWrapperBase*)self)->cdata
```

Yeah, that works. You can look at all the implementations of [Python's built-in types](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects) and see that they do pretty much the same thing, usually without checking whether they're operating on a subclass instance.

Comment: Oh really? So is it always like it, that fields and other stuff needed in a subclass is laid out in memory after data of it's base class? Is that a part of some standard, or it's just how is Python always implemented?

Comment: @wesolyromek: It's how the CPython implementation works. Note that "fields" defined in Python are usually `__dict__` entries rather than the kind of struct fields you'd define in C, so Python-level subclasses don't usually do much to the memory layout of their superclasses. (If you use `__slots__`, that changes things.)

Comment: So (as long as I don't use `__slots__`) it works like this: all objects' layouts start with what their C base classes have, and then only some pointers of these dictionaries and other fields are modified to get subclasses, right?

Comment: @wesolyromek: `__dict__` usually gets added to the layout, and `__weakref__`, a thing involved in supporting weak references, sometimes gets added too. There's also a weird case where the `__dict__` can appear *before* the superclass parts of the object layout if the superclass has variable-length instances, like with `tuple`. In that case, the `PyObject *` that points to the object actually points somewhere in the middle, so you still don't need to do anything special to handle subclass instances.